# Question about Log4jAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

i have started learning something about log4j as so far its working fine here is the code from the log4j.property file

```
    # Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1,xml



# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
# ${applicationRoot}/logs/xml.log
log4j.appender.xml=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.xml.File=G:/TESTGEN/logs/xmlimpex.log
log4j.appender.xml.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.xml.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.xml.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.xml.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

and its working perfectly fine printing on the console as well logging to the file.I am wondering is it possible to do something as follow

i want that i should be able to log everything on the console which what this log4j file is doing 
but on the same time i want that in the log file which i have configured using `RollingFileAppender` should log entries only for warning and errors.

Please suggest me how i can do this

Thanks in advance
Umesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,A1
log4j.newlogger=WARN, XML
```

Log4j works in this way: You can create multiple loggers which fit in a hiearchy where the Root logger is always at the top. Loggers can inherit levels and appenders (if the additivity flag is on) from parent loggers.

In the example I gave you, the new logger that you created is triggered at a WARN level. It has as appenders XML but also A1 (which it inherited from the Root logger).

Note that if we hadn't set the level of newLogger, it would have inherited the level DEBUG.

Hiearchies in log4j work like in java packages (using dots) and rely on the logger names. Logger X is the parent of logger X.Y which is the parent of logger X.Y.Z. Logger X is always the child of the Root logger.

You can read more about this in the [Log4j introduction](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of Log4net it says somewhere that you can set which levels to be handled from the appender.